# MPMediaPlayback no audio ios 8

Tags: ios, video, ios8, video-capture

My application capture video. I have checked that video file has a sound but in application it is not playing with MPMoviePlayerController. I have noticed that for short video, less than 5 seconds, sound is playing.

```
 -(void) showMovie:(NSString*)moviePath{
        [self initializeMoviePlayer:moviePath];
        [self setMoviePath:moviePath];

        [movieController play];   
    }

    -(void) initializeMoviePlayer:(NSString*)moviePath{
        if (movieController == nil) {
            movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
            movieController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

            [movieController prepareToPlay];
            [movieController setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
            [movieController setShouldAutoplay:YES];
            [movieController setControlStyle:2];


            movieController.fullscreen = YES;
            movieController.scalingMode =MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
            movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
            movieController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

            [movieController.view setFrame: self.frame];

            [self insertSubview:self.movieController.view atIndex:0];
        }
    }
```

- Update:
  Have added a bug in apple bug reporter with id 18823656